# Android problem with pass data in other Activity's

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

hello hope you doing well

I have problem with passing data to another page idk why I'm sure of code so please can
anyone help

this is my login code

```
myref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds1:snapshot.getChildren())
        {

            Donors a=ds1.getValue(Donors.class);
            if(Ad_Email.getText().toString().equals(a.d_email)&& ad_pass.getText().toString().equals(a.d_pass))
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }


        if(flag==0)
            Toast.makeText(donor_login.this,"Invalid User",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Donor_page.class);
            intent.putExtra("email",Ad_Email.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

i want pass the email in this page but when i run it the email not show idk why

```
 donate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
            emaildonor.setText(email);

        }
    });

}
```

this error come in layout

```
 2020-12-24 00:50:52.338 12910-13062/com.example.adopt_pet_app W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0xe16cd808 disconnect failed
2020-12-24 00:50:52.338 12910-13062/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0xe37852a0, 0xe16cd800
2020-12-24 00:50:52.358 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/ViewRootImpl@cf4b434[donor_login]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x5 surface={false 0} changed=true
2020-12-24 00:50:52.360 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/ViewRootImpl@cf4b434[donor_login]: stopped(true) old=false
2020-12-24 00:52:51.008 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@c9ad26f[Donor_page]
2020-12-24 00:52:51.009 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-12-24 00:52:51.009 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=com.example.adopt_pet_app ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
2020-12-24 00:52:51.010 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2020-12-24 00:52:51.010 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2020-12-24 00:52:51.015 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=76
2020-12-24 00:52:51.016 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=86
2020-12-24 00:52:51.545 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/ViewRootImpl@95dfa80[Donor_page]: stopped(true) old=false
2020-12-24 00:52:56.108 12910-13062/com.example.adopt_pet_app W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0xcf042808 disconnect failed
2020-12-24 00:52:56.109 12910-13062/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0xe17af620, 0xcf042800
2020-12-24 00:52:56.140 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/ViewRootImpl@95dfa80[Donor_page]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x5 surface={false 0} changed=false
2020-12-24 00:52:56.141 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/ViewRootImpl@95dfa80[Donor_page]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
2020-12-24 00:52:56.142 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@c9ad26f[Donor_page]
2020-12-24 00:52:56.142 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-12-24 00:53:03.743 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/ViewRootImpl@95dfa80[Donor_page]: stopped(false) old=true
2020-12-24 00:53:03.769 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/ViewRootImpl@95dfa80[Donor_page]: stopped(false) old=false
2020-12-24 00:53:03.831 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/ViewRootImpl@95dfa80[Donor_page]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x7 surface={true 3782006784} changed=true
2020-12-24 00:53:03.838 12910-13062/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
2020-12-24 00:53:03.838 12910-13062/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0xe17af620, 0xe16cd808
2020-12-24 00:53:03.905 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/ViewRootImpl@95dfa80[Donor_page]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
2020-12-24 00:53:03.905 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@c9ad26f[Donor_page]
2020-12-24 00:53:03.906 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-12-24 00:53:03.918 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@c9ad26f[Donor_page]
2020-12-24 00:53:03.918 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-12-24 00:53:03.918 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=com.example.adopt_pet_app ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
2020-12-24 00:53:03.919 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2020-12-24 00:53:03.919 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2020-12-24 00:53:03.954 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=78
2020-12-24 00:53:03.954 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=76
2020-12-24 00:53:05.609 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/ViewRootImpl@95dfa80[Donor_page]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
2020-12-24 00:53:05.609 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@c9ad26f[Donor_page]
2020-12-24 00:53:05.609 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-12-24 00:53:05.640 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/ViewRootImpl@95dfa80[Donor_page]: stopped(true) old=false
2020-12-24 00:53:05.673 12910-13062/com.example.adopt_pet_app W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0xe16cd808 disconnect failed
2020-12-24 00:53:05.673 12910-13062/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0xe17af620, 0xe16cd800
2020-12-24 00:53:05.690 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/ViewRootImpl@95dfa80[Donor_page]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x5 surface={false 0} changed=true
2020-12-24 00:53:05.949 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=78
2020-12-24 00:53:06.494 12910-12910/com.example.adopt_pet_app D/ViewRootImpl@95dfa80[Donor_page]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={false 0} changed=false
```

If any one can help i will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code below :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
     String email = extras.getString("email");
     emaildonor.setText(email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting data in wrong way you should do like this

```
donate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String email =intent.getStringExtra("email");
        emaildonor.setText(email);

    }
});
```

or You shuuld get data in on Create

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
            String email =intent.getStringExtra("email");
            emaildonor.setText(email);
```

Answer (score 0):

You displayed email on OnClick of `donate` button so it's will display when you click on `donate` button. So call your email display code outside of `OnClickListener`

```
donate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           
        }
    });

 String email = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
 emaildonor.setText(email);

}
```